# The reason of error when I put += in dictionary but not in =

Tags: python, dictionary

When I run below Python (3.6) code, I get an error (see the # KeyError noted line). But when I change the dictionary[res] += 1 to dictionary[res] = 1, it runs well. Considering that the dict usually allows operator '+=', don't know why not this time. Someone knows the reason?

```
words = ["gin", "zen", "gig", "msg"]
Morse = [".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.", "--.", "....", "..", ".---", "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.", "---",".--.", "--.-", ".-.", "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--.."]
dictionary = {}

for _ in words:
    tmp = []
    for c in _:
        tmp.append(Morse[ord(c) - ord('a')])  # take the code
    res = ''.join(tmp)
    dictionary[res] += 1  # KeyError
cnt = 0
for i in enumerate(dictionary):
    cnt += 1
```

Error msg is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<input>", line 10, in <module>
KeyError: '--...-.'
```

Comment: Because that key doesn't exist, you could use a `defaultdict` or `Counter`.

Comment: Use dict.get(key, default = None).

Comment: The difference between `+=` and `=` is that the former assumes that something already exists there. In your case it does not. What is the purpose of your dictionary, without understanding that its difficult to suggest the best solution. Note: its also bad for to use `_` as the name of a variable that you actually use.

Comment: Thank you so much! That is exactly right, oh men. The reason for using the dictionary is to count how many duplicate Morse code bunches for a word (thus confusing to hear) from the given set of words list. i.e. "gin" -> "--...-.", "zen" -> "--...-.", so two words are of a kind, which I tried to use dict to identify its kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between `+=` and `=` is that the former assumes that something already exists there and `=` is an assignment, creating the entry if it does not already exist. Your `dict` has no entries, so `+=` is an invalid operation.

You can use `Counter`, which is effectively a `dict` where the values are `ints` and have a default value of 0.

```
from collections import Counter

words = ["gin", "zen", "gig", "msg"]
Morse = [".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.", "--.", "....", "..", ".---", "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.", "---",".--.", "--.-", ".-.", "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--.."]
dictionary = Counter()

for w in words:
    tmp = []
    for c in w:
        tmp.append(Morse[ord(c) - ord('a')])  # take the code
    res = ''.join(tmp)
    dictionary[res] += 1

print(dictionary)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I learned a great deal today. God bless you!

Answer (score 1):

Inside your for loop your dictionary continues empty, so it doesn't has the key `[res]`.

And just more one thing it's not a good practice you use `underscore` as variables names.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that, maybe the `underscore` is confusing to something?

Comment: no, it is just what we call `python naming convention`